# JOI :allow null values in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js, joi

I am trying to add a validation for array in a POST request

```
Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).single().optional()
```

I need to allow null values in the payload. Can you please tell me how this can be done ?

Comment: Can you use any.allow(null) method ?. Here is doc

https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v10.1.0/API.md#anyallowvalue

Comment: I tried both any and allow(null), did not work .

Comment: Are you trying to allow null values inside the array or null instead of the array?

Comment: just don't pass anything , null instead of array .

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you want to allow the array to be null use:

```
Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).allow(null);
```

If you want to allow  null or whitespace strings inside the array use:

```
Joi.array().items(Joi.string().allow(null).allow(''));
```

Example:

```
const Joi = require('joi');

var schema = Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).allow(null);

var arr = null;

var result = Joi.validate(arr, schema); 

console.log(result); // {error: null}

arr = ['1', '2'];

result = Joi.validate(arr, schema);

console.log(result); // {error: null}


var insideSchema = Joi.array().items(Joi.string().allow(null).allow(''));

var insideResult = Joi.validate(['1', null, '2'], insideSchema);

console.log(insideResult);
```

Comment: Thank you :), this is perfect

Comment: I apologize this isn't perfectly on topic but I've searched for a while without an example and this is super close. I have an array of values but when I pass only 1 value in I get an error `"query.fields must be an array"` so Joi isn't converting the single item to an array before validating. If I pass two or more it passes validation. So I can't seem to get an array with one value in it:
`fields: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().valid("val1", "valu2"))` Any idea here?

Answer (score 4):

the very short answer is:

```
name: Joi.string().allow(null)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know what i'm posting is not what you are looking for,
but as i was ran into similar type of problem.

so my problem was: I do not want to allow empty array in my object

my solution:

```
// if you have array of numbers

key: joi.array().items(joi.number().required()).strict().required()

// if you have array of strings

key: joi.array().items(joi.string().required()).strict().required()
```