# How to convert/transform "null" value to an empty array with Joi?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, validation, joi

I would like to convert/transform into an empty array if the value is `null` but when I add the `custom` method of Joi on my `list` schema, it doesn't seem to pass by and the value is never converted. I'll always receive `null` :

```js
Joi.list().allow(null).custom((value) => {
                if (value === null) {
                    return [];
                }

                return value;
            });
```

```js
Joi.list().allow(null).custom((value) => {
                if (value === null) {
                    return [];
                }

                return [];
            });
```

**Both examples above doesn't work**

*If value === null, convert to []*

*Else do nothing*

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Your syntax may be wrong. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470251/joi-allow-null-values-in-array

Comment: @AndreFeijo I do not have any problem with `null`, but I would like to convert it into an empty array when I get `null` as value.

Comment: @AndreFeijo the `custom` method is never read and so, `null` will never be transformed to anything else and I don't understand why `custom` doesn't work here..